# spring security oauth2 JWT refresh token returns "Authentication failed: invalid_token Cannot convert access token to JSON"

Tags: java, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, refresh-token

I have implemented `spring-security-oauth2` using JWT and the initial authentication and the request for resources works normally, as does the token enhancer. When I attempt to get a new JWT using the refresh token I get the error `"cannot convert access token to JSON"`

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // ....
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        converter.setSigningKey(jwtSigningKey);
        converter.setVerifierKey(jwtSigningKey);
        return converter;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        Base64Utility base64 = new Base64Utility();
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(ApplicationConstants.CLIENT)
                .resourceIds(securityConstants.audience)
                .secret(...)
                .scopes(AuthorizationConstants.READ)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(securityConstants.getAccessTokenValiditySeconds())
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(securityConstants.getRefreshTokenValiditySeconds());
    }
}
```

The access_token which is returned is the normal `three.part.token`, and the `refresh_token` is like this: `22cc0513-8a19-42bb-9bd4-631c6758a273`

I used this Javascript code to try to refresh it:

```
function refreshToken() {
    var client = jwtForm.client.value;
    var clientSecret = getClientSecret();

    var data = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + jwt.refresh_token;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", authServer + "/oauth/token");
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(client + ":" + atob(clientSecret)));
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            processResponse(xhr);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my custom JwtAccessTokenConverter. You have to call super.enchance in the enhance method if you aren't going to create your own refresh token. Once I called super.enhance it created a JWT refresh token.